# Efficient intersection of sets?

Tags: c++, set, std

I'm wondering what the most efficient way of doing this is.

I have points  that I gather from 2 places.

I am only interested in the points which are common to both places.

My plan is to have 3 `std::set<Point>` . First I will add in the points from area A,into set A then points from B into set B and let set C be the intersection of both sets.

However, I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this that involves maybe less sets?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a geometrical description of the overlap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is so common that there even is a (named in an obvious way) [standard algorithm `set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) for you to use.

Comment: Isn't this the solution OP was trying to improve upon?

Comment: @mpartel, if there was a space for improvement, the standard library would surely include it. The standard algorithms are there for you to use them. If they were bad, no-one would use them, but actually the recommendation of the C++ community is to always prefer a standard algorithm over a hand written loop or own version of the algorithm (even suffering from terminal case of NIH is not a reason to avoid them).

Comment: Certainly, they are very good implementations for the problems they do solve, but they don't directly solve all variations of every problem optimally. e.g. 'Useless' gave a very plausible improvement that exploited some reasonable assumptions that may well hold in the OP's case. (Of course all the usual warnings about premature optimization and benchmarking are still relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do away with set B: first gather points from A into set A, then gather points from B, but place them into C only if they are also present in A.

If sets A and B are of different (and predictable) sizes, the obvious choice would be to eliminate the larger one.

Comment: What is set's contains function?

Comment: @Milo The same as the one you're using now for sets A, B, and C.

Comment: @Milo This answer tries to answer the question as posed (as do the other ones). If you don't understand how to use sets, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The naive set-based approach (built two sets, and then generate the intersection), has the following steps:

1. build `std::set A` from source 1. Say source 1 has N points, this is:

   - O(N log N) time, O(N) space
2. build `std::set B` from source 2. Say this has M points, giving:

   - O(M log M) time, O(M) space
3. `std::set_intersection`

   - O(M+N) time and space

The slightly improved set-based approach is:

1. build `std::set` A from the first source (same complexity as above)
2. for every point in the second source, add it to the result if (and only if) it's in set A

   - O(M log N) time, linear space
   - so, you avoided O(M) extra space allocated, and the extra O(M+N) intersection step.

   You'd implement this using `std::set` like so:

   ```
   if (a.find(point) != a.end())
       result.insert(point);
   ```

Note that if you know which point source is going to provide fewer points, you should use that source to build set A for best performance. If your sources provide points in sorted order, you can avoid the sets entirely and save even more space & time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `map<Point, int>` where each point is mapped to the number of times it appears, i.e. 1 or 2. Then delete all points that appeared only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map<Point,int>` to store the points occuring 1 or 2 times. You will also have to overload the `<` operator in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think approach with three sets and std::set_intersection is the most logical and efficient. Although if you really want to have less sets you can just iterate through set B and remove points which are not in A then iterate through set A and remove points which are not in B. This should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a lexicographical `operator<` on points, i.e. (extrapolate for >2 dimensions if needed)

```
bool operator<(Point const &a, Point const &b)
{
    if (a.x != b.x) return a.x < b.x;
    return a.y < b.y;
}
```

Then it's possible that `std::set` will have good enough performance to compute the intersection efficiently.  Assuming your two groups are already in arrays, or generated on the fly, you need 2 sets:

```
A = { all points from A }
C = { }
for all points in B:
    if point is in A:
        add point to C
```

If you're using floating-point coordinates, then you probably need to allow for floating-point errors and search for all points in `A` *near* each point in `B`.  Then you want a spatial partition structure such as a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) or [quadtree/octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree),.  That would involve bringing in a new library or coding up a fairly complex data structure, so I would avoid it if possible.